# Test and Extract a multi-lined text using Regex and Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to **TEST** based on a certain feature and **FETCH** the containing block of data using regex in python. In short, this pseudo code explain what I want to achieve.

```
If (Color feature is in the block message):
   bring that block
```

This a sample of the data that I have in str.txt file

```
.
.
This file contains various types of data formats and blocks

Country of the survey
CONTRY CODE: AAAA
POPULATION: 11111
GDP RANK: 22222

.
BLOCK MESSAGE
      BLOCK A:
LENGTH(M): 1.6
WEIGHT(KG):    76
    DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE

FAMILY MEMBERS: 3

END BLOCK

BLOCK MESSAGE

    BLOCK B:
EYE COLOR: BLACK

LENGTH(M): 1.9
     WEIGHT(KG): 89
DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
   CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
           FAMILY MEMBERS: 1
END BLOCK
BLOCK MESSAGE
BLOCK C:
     LENGTH(M): 17
WEIGHT(KG): 90
        DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): Y

CHRONIC DISEASE: Yes
FAMILY MEMBERS: 4
END BLOCK

BLOCK MESSAGE
   BLOCK D:
   LENGTH(M): 195
   WEIGHT(KG): 90
   EYE COLOR: BROWN
DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
FAMILY MEMBERS: 2
END BLOCK

.
.
```

What I am expecting to obtain is

```
BLOCK MESSAGE
BLOCK B:
EYE COLOR: BLACK
LENGTH(M): 1.9
WEIGHT(KG): 89
DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
FAMILY MEMBERS: 1
END BLOCK

BLOCK MESSAGE
BLOCK D:
LENGTH(M): 195
WEIGHT(KG): 90
EYE COLOR: BROWN
DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
FAMILY MEMBERS: 2
END BLOCK
```

My question is that how can I get the block messages from "BLOCK MESSAGE" to "END BLOCK" which have an eye color feature? Taking into account the following criteria:

1. The text may have different blocks of data.
2. Many spaces and new lines may be contained.
3. The required feature "EYE COLOR" may have different position in the messages.

I will be highly regarded if there is any explanation of the idea(s) and the code(s) for this issue.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: It will make it a much better and clearer question if you 1) shorten it and 2) add the regex you tried.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use loops:

1. Open the text file and start reading file per line
2. Read line till finding the begining of a block
3. Read line till the end of this block
4. Check if this block contains a color
5. If 4 is verified, add block to the outputs
6. Return in 2

#### NOTE:

- You can simply check if a line contains a string with the operator `in`.
- I use the regex module to replace the space at the begining of the line (just for prettier output).

#### Code:

```
# Import regex module
import re

# Save block in a list
output = []
# Open file
with open("../temp.txt", "r")  as f:
    # Read file line per line
    line = f.readline()
    # While not at the end of file
    while line:
        # Search beginning block with "BLOCK MESSAGE"
        if "BLOCK MESSAGE" in line:
            # Init block variable
            block = ""

            # Loop till the string "END BLOCK"
            while line and "END BLOCK" not in line:
                # Add line
                block += line
                # Read next line
                line = f.readline()

            # If COLOR is in the block
            if "COLOR" in block:
                # Add the last line ("END BLOCK")
                block += line
                # Remove space begining line
                block = re.sub(r'\n\s+', '\n', block)
                # Add block to the outputs
                output.append(block)
        # Read next line
        line = f.readline()
```

#### Output:

```
print(output)
# ['BLOCK MESSAGE\nBLOCK B:\nEYE COLOR: BLACK\nLENGTH(M): 1.9\nWEIGHT(KG): 89\nDISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N\nCHRONIC DISEASE: NONE\nFAMILY MEMBERS: 1\nEND BLOCK\n',
#  'BLOCK MESSAGE\nBLOCK D:\nLENGTH(M): 195\nWEIGHT(KG): 90\nEYE COLOR: BROWN\nDISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N\nCHRONIC DISEASE: NONE\nFAMILY MEMBERS: 2\nEND BLOCK\n']

[ print(o) for o in output]
# BLOCK MESSAGE
# BLOCK B:
# EYE COLOR: BLACK
# LENGTH(M): 1.9
# WEIGHT(KG): 89
# DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
# CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
# FAMILY MEMBERS: 1
# END BLOCK

# BLOCK MESSAGE
# BLOCK D:
# LENGTH(M): 195
# WEIGHT(KG): 90
# EYE COLOR: BROWN
# DISSABLITIY STATUS(Y/N): N
# CHRONIC DISEASE: NONE
# FAMILY MEMBERS: 2
# END BLOCK
```

Comment: Appropriate your effort, but it is required to use regex.